# Ruby on rails: Code for autofill form from the database depending on one field in ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form called cattle finances, in this form, i use collection select to input the batch number, i have other form columns shown in the _form.html.erb code below

```
 <%= simple_form_for @cattle_finance, remote: true do |f|   %>
 <% if @cattle_finance.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cattle_finance.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cattle_finance from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @cattle_finance.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>
  <br>
   <%= f.collection_select :batch_number, CattleList.all, :batch_number, :batch_number, :prompt => "please select Batch Number"  %></br>
   <%= f.input  :total_litres_of_batch, as: :integer %>
   <%= f.input  :total_income, as: :integer %>
   <%= f.input  :gross_income, as: :integer %>
   <%= f.input  :total_expenses, as: :integer %>
   <%= f.input  :net_income, as: :integer %>
   <%= f.input  :date,    as: :date %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

My index.html.erb code is

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
     <h2>Cattle Finances</h2>
   </div>

 <div class"btn-group menu2" align = right>
 <%= link_to raw("<span class=''></span> Creditors"), cattle_creditors_path, :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
 <%= link_to raw("<span class=''></span> Debtors"), cattle_debtors_path, :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
 <%= link_to raw("<span class=''></span> Cattle"), cattles_path, :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
 <%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class=>"btn btn-default" unless current_page?(root_url) %>


 </div>

   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
     <%= link_to new_cattle_finance_path, remote: true do %>
       <button class="btn btn-default">New</button>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="cattle_finance-form" style="display:none;"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="" id="cattle_finances"><%= render @cattle_finances %></div>
 </div>
```

So what is need help with is the way in which i can select a particular batch_number and automatically all other fields are populated, or picked from the database from the corresponding database tables and filled in respectively. Any help his highly appreciated coz am stuck, although
i know what i want to do, I have no idea of how i can start.

Comment: you have to make ajax call, and on success of ajax update the form..

Comment: any help on how i can do that?

Comment: Yes, I would start [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).  If you get stuck, update this post or create a new one with your non-working code and error messages.

Comment: @steve klein i have changed my code by making it create a new form in ajax, any help with the code i can use to auto fill my form on input of one form field?